# Why can't I delete this directory?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

What is going on here?

```
dave@dave-desktop:/mnt/w/Source/Sign/dist$ ls -la
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 1 dave dave 512 Feb 27 08:55 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 dave dave 512 Feb 27 09:09 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 dave dave 512 Feb 27 09:09 signage
dave@dave-desktop:/mnt/w/Source/Sign/dist$ rmdir signage
rmdir: failed to remove 'signage': Permission denied
dave@dave-desktop:/mnt/w/Source/Sign/dist$ rm -rf signage
rm: cannot remove 'signage': Permission denied
dave@dave-desktop:/mnt/w/Source/Sign/dist$ whoami
dave
```

This is on "Ubuntu" running on windows 10 WSL.

Comment: Is WSL outside the scope of U&L because it's essentially Windows emulating an environment?  Similar to asking a `wine` question on a MS Windows site? ...

Comment: Maybe.  Running Linux in a VM on windows is also technically emulation.  But there are certainly some extreme differences between the two.  For example, netstat doesn't work at all, ps shows a limited process list, etc.  Still, all I'm looking for is, is there anything going on here that would cause this on a linux system?  If not, then I'm happy with just assuming this is Windows shenanigans.

Comment: The `/mnt` prefix indicates that this may be removable storage of some kind. Is this a mounted filesystem, and what type?

Comment: W: on /mnt/w type drvfs (rw,noatime,uid=1000,gid=1000,case=off)

Comment: @Dave you are not running Linux. However you are running a Unix (GNU on WSL).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor `uname -a` says this funny line on mine: "Linux x250 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft #523-Microsoft Mon Dec 31 17:49:00 PST 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux"

Comment: you can't remove files on a read only system nor when the directory above does not have correct permissions or when the OS is locking the directory or the file itself (try `lsof` for that)

Comment: You are correct that it was locked.  lsof shows nothing, but I found it with windows process explorer.  I had a cmd.exe open in that directory.

Comment: @Freddy you found a bug. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux The correct string is something like `WSL x250 4.4.0-17134-Microsoft #523-Microsoft Mon Dec 31 17:49:00 PST 2018 x86_64 GNU/WSL`. People have been struggling for years with naming this OS. Two of the biggest causes of bugs in programming are: Naming things, null pointers, and out by one errors.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I agree with you that "WSL" should be at least somewhere in the string to make it distinguishable. It seems that kernel-release or kernel-version with "Microsoft" is all we get. The bash screenshot (right top on the wikipedia site) looks similar to mine.

Comment: @Rinzwind is onto something. I got this error when trying to remove a file that was open on the Windows side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't even delete this directory from MS-Windows.

I found it with Windows process explorer.

**It was locked. lsof shows nothing, but I found it with windows process explorer. I had a cmd.exe open in that directory.**

Answer (score 3):

Permissions don't work as expected in mounted Windows directories in WSL.

See this example:

```
root@x250:/mnt/c/Temp# touch foo
root@x250:/mnt/c/Temp# ls -l foo
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ibm ibm 0 Feb 27 15:25 foo
root@x250:/mnt/c/Temp# chmod -v 644 foo
mode of 'foo' changed from 0777 (rwxrwxrwx) to 0644 (rw-r--r--)
root@x250:/mnt/c/Temp# ls -l foo
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ibm ibm 0 Feb 27 15:25 foo
```

Yuck!

Comment: I just want to know, What do people expect about permissions on NTFS. It has much more complex ACL model and only use SID(including user/group). So, why can we mount a NTFS without SID-UID/GID mapping and expect it work like a normal linux filesystem?

Answer (score -4):

If the account "dave", which was used to create the directory, has root privileges, try `sudo rm -r signage`

Comment: `sudo` is not the solution to all problems, though it is often the cause.